# CP2102 USB pull-up current consumption

Tags: cp2102

I'm not sure, what the current consumption of the CP2102 is, when no USB is connected. In the datasheet it states:

https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/368/cp2102n_datasheet-1634912.pdf

[image]

And there is this USB pull-up specification. What does this mean? When no USB cable is connected, it draws around 200uA?

Comment: Did you read the footnote 3?

Comment: Ah i get it now, these currents are just from the pull-up. So the controller will always draw some decent amount.

Comment: The pull-up current is not consumed if USB cable is disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the CP2102 doesn't always power down into suspend mode, so it draws 20mA even when the USB cable is disconnected.